# ravendb database backup - returns 401

Tags: ravendb, database-backups

I am testing backup and restore of ravendb,

so this works properly:

```
Raven.Backup.exe --url=http://app-dev-01.web:8080/ --dest=C:\Temp\RavenDbBackup2
```

and i get my backup.

but when I execute it for a different database such as:

```
Raven.Backup.exe --url=http://app-dev-01.web:8080/databases/someDatabase --dest=C:\Temp\RavenBackup
```

I get:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I can not find anything in logfiles, and both operations are run by the same user, who has sufficient  permissions.

any idee why I get this error?

thanks

almir

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I'm getting the same problem!

Comment: yes! I think the reason was that we used it in intranet and raven did not need any authentication. but as much as I can remember there was a patch for raven and afterward  it worked

Answer (score 0):

I am currently stuck on build 992 of RavenDB due to a dependency of another component I use which I cannot update right now.

The resolution which worked for me was to set the `Raven/AnonymousAccess` configuration value on the server to `Get` (it was previously `All`) and make sure that the calling application sets the following:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
    ...
}
```